# How to access and use a value from a child component on redux-form to make a checkbox work and enable conditionally rendered extra options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I'm using redux-form. I need to conditionally render extra options on user click of a checkbox in a child component.

I am able to do this on the parent file (in the SOW Type section of the form) using 'formValueSelector' (see sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/currying-cloud-isu8c) but on the third option in this section ('Custom Professional Services SOW') on clicking the checkbox I need to further condionally render some options on clicking the new checkbox that is exposed inside ('Customised Professional Services').

The file containing the code for the child component is 'CustomProfExtOptions'. What code do I need in this child component and/or the parent component in order to get this nested checkbox to work/enable conditional rendering on checking the box

I understand I need to access the value of the field in this child component on the form in order to manipulate it's state (mapStateToProps?) and allow the conditional rendering to work. I have done this successfully in the parent (as the sandbox shows) but I don't know how to get his working in the child component.

I have googled extensively on this for three days and tried to tweak other examples I have found to fit this specific problem (the greyed out text at the bottom of 'CustomProfExtOptions.js' where the child component code is held) but I've yet to find anything that works.

**What is working so far:**

The 'formValueSelector' code (as per the Redux-Form docs which allows access the values in the fields of the form) I am using in the parent container for the form (a file called 'PdfGenFormContainerRedux.js') is as follows:

```
PdfGenFormContainerRedux = reduxForm({
  form: "StatementOfWorkApplication"
})(PdfGenFormContainerRedux);

const selector = formValueSelector("StatementOfWorkApplication");
PdfGenFormContainerRedux = connect((state) => {
  const hasProductSowValue = selector(state, "productSOW");
  const hasTeradataExtOptionsValue = selector(state, "teradata");
  const hasCustomProfExtOptions = selector(state, "customExtOptions"); //selector created

  return {
    hasProductSowValue,
    hasTeradataExtOptionsValue,
    hasCustomProfExtOptions
  };
})(PdfGenFormContainerRedux);

export default PdfGenFormContainerRedux;
```

This allows me to conditionally render the second hidden field on the click of the checkbox by using a variable called **props.hasCustomProfExtOptions** as demonstrated below:

```
<div className="checkbox-group">
        <div>
          <label className="checkbox-group">
            <Field
              name="customExtOptions"
              className="form-checkbox"
              component="input"
              type="checkbox"
            />
            Custom Professional Services SOW
            {props.hasCustomProfExtOptions && ( //conditional rendering bit here
              <div>
                <Field
                  name="custProfServices"
                  type="input"
                  component={CustomProfExtOptions}
                  label="Custom Options Info"
                  placeholder="Location"
                  formId={formId}
                  /* hasProfServ={props.hasProfServ} */
                />
              </div>
            )}
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

This works fine on the parent container but how do I get it working on the checkbox labelled 'Customised Professional Services' in the child component? (the file called 'CustomProfExtOptions')

Just to add, i need any input from this nested section to be included in the final submission of the form.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure I get it right but if you add `hasProfServ={props.hasCustomProfExtOptions}` in your `Field` whose name is "custProfServices", then its value will be available in `CustomProfExtOptions` component.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried, 

 'hasProfServ={props.hasProfServ}' 



from line 214 (in 'PdfGenFormContainerRedux.js', which selects the field name from the child component i.e. 

const hasProfServ = selector(state, "custProfServiceTwo");) and added it as a prop in the relevant field as you suggested but when i tried to access it as a prop in the child component it just shows undefined?

***(hasCustomProfExtOptions*** relates to the main checkbox not the nested one so this won't work)